# Rfid Mfrc522 not working using long cable

Tags: spi, rfid

I am doing a project using Arduino and a Rfid Mfrc522 module that consists of reading a card to unlock/lock a door. The Arduino is 3 meters far away from the Rfid Mfrc522 module and I used 7 cables to connect it, according to the schematic of the Mfrc522 Arduino library. When I previously tested the system everything was working fine but after I connect the Arduino to the module with the 3 meters cable I get this output and I can not read any card.

```
Firmware Version: = (unknown)
Scan PICC to see UID, SAK, type, and data blocks...
```

When I try to run the firmware check example for the library I get the following output

```
*****************************
MFRC522 Digital self test
*****************************
Firmware Version: = (unknown)
-----------------------------
Only known versions supported
-----------------------------
Performing test...
-----------------------------
Result: DEFECT or UNKNOWN
```

Is it possible that 3 meters away from Arduino the module is unable to communicate with it? If so what can be a possible solution to extend the "communication range" between both of them?

Thanks for the help,

Enzo

Comment: You are using 7 individual wires? That sounds bad, because that's 7 antennas. While I can't say that it will work, I'd at least try a shielded cable (you can try a standard CAT-5 cable)

Comment: Try slowing down your SPI communication. Also quadruple-check your wiring.

Comment: @PMF Thanks for the answer I will try to do that. So the issue is that each cable interferes with each other or the noise outside in air interfere with the 7 cables? Because my cat 5 cable I have at home is shielded between the 8 wires and the surroundings, not between each other. Thanks

Comment: @Majenko Thanks that could also help, do you know how I can do this in the Arduino code editor?

Comment: Depends on what library you are using. Read this: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SPISetClockDivider

Comment: @Enzo Both could be an issue. That's why good CAT-5 cables use twisted pairs, which filters interferences between two wires. I can't say which ones to put together for an SPI connection, though.

Comment: Don't use the `SPISetClockDivider()` as it is a deprecated method since 2014. Using the [SPISettings()](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SPISettings) object to setup SPI configuration. If you are using [this library](https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid) it allows you to define a [variable](https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid/blob/master/src/MFRC522.h#L21-L23) to set the clock speed and pass it in to the SPISettings object. By default, the SPI clock is set at 4MHz, I would suggest you try change it to 1MHz.